# Cauchy Integral Question

Tags: integration, complex-numbers, complex-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

> Evaluate $$\int_{\gamma}\frac{z^2+z^7}{(z-\frac{e}{3})^3}$$ here $\gamma$ is a rectangular path traversed in the counter clockwise direction with vertices $1,2i,−1,−2i$.

So my thoughts for this question there's a singularity at $z=e/3$ which lies inside and then apply Cauchy-Integral formula (is there any other requirements needed here, maybe holomorphic?)

$$\int_{\gamma} \frac{f(z)}{(z-w)^{n+1}} dz = \frac{2 \pi i f^{(n)}(w)}{n!}$$ here $n=2$ so do we just evaluate at $\frac{e}{3}$ which would get us $$\pi i (\frac{e^2}{9} + \frac{e^7}{2187})$$

Is this the way to go about this Q, I have a feeling I may have done something wrong

Thank you

Comment: Yes, $f$ has to be holomorphic everywhere inside the curve. But rest easy. Polynomials are holomorphic everywhere. But for your evaluation, note that it is of $f^{(n)}$, but your answer was calculated with $f$.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense

Comment: Your end result is incorrect, you never took the second derivative in the integral formula. Check my result for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have, by Cauchy's integral formula, that

\begin{align}
\int_\gamma \frac{z^2+z^7}{(z-\frac{e}{3})^3}dz&=\frac{2 \pi i}{2!} \bigg( f''(z^2+z^7)\bigg\vert_{z=\frac{e}{3}}\bigg)\\
&=\pi i (2+42z^5)\bigg\vert_{z=\frac{e}{3}}\\
&=\pi i (2+42\frac{e^5}{3^5})\\
&=\pi i (2+14 \frac{e^5}{3^4})\\
&=2\pi i + \frac{14\pi i e^5}{81}
\end{align}
as needed.